# A proper way to reuse existing type definitions

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When using a react component that passes some props to another react child component, I find myself rewriting some type definitions to the parent that was already defined in the child component.

```
interface ParentProps {
    onChange: (value: string) => void; // I end up rewriting this, when it was already written on ChildProps interface.
}

const Parent: React.FC<ParentProps> = ({ onChange }) => {
    return <Child onChange={onChange} label="Label 1" />;
};

// Child component. Could be imported from a third party library.
interface ChildProps {
    onChange: (value: string) => void;
    label: string;
}
const Child: React.FC<ChildProps> = ({ onChange }) => {
    return <MyComponent onChange={onChange} />;
};
```

Are there any techniques to avoid rewriting type definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends how much of `ChildProps` you want to reuse.

If you want to reuse just a couple of properties, you can use in indexed type query to get the type of a specific property:

```
interface ParentProps {
    onChange: ChildProps['onChange']
}
```

Or you can define `ParentProps` to extend `ChildProps` if you want to reuse all properties:

```
interface ParentProps extends ChildProps {
}
```

Or you can pick just a subset using `Pick`:

```
interface ParentProps extends Pick<ChildProps, 'onChange'>  { // Pick<ChildProps, 'onChange' | 'label'> to pick more
}
```

Or if you want to pick all except a subset you can use `Omit`

```
interface ParentProps extends Omit<ChildProps, 'label'>  { // Omit<ChildProps, 'onChange' | 'label'> to omit more
}
```